# Django user turns into Anonymous User

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to perform django authentication using a custom user model. Note this is for a school project and not

I have the following User model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    userID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        db_table = "User"
        app_label = "funbids"
        managed = False
```

I have my model defined in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'funbids.User'
```

I'm also using a custom auth backend. Note this is just a test using cleartext passwords (I'm aware this is a terrible idea to do in any production environment). I'm using a custom auth backend because a requirement for this app is to authenticate using raw SQL queries with an existing database.

```
class AuthBackend(object):
    """
    Authenticate a user in funbids
    """

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        # Test credentials
        cursor = connections["funbids"].cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE username=%s AND password=%s", [username, password])
        if cursor.fetchone():
            # Have to grab the model, then authenticate
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            return user
        else:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Everything seems to work in my login view.

```
def login_user(request, login_failed=False):
    # Redirect the user to the index if they're already authenticated and arrive at the login page
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("funbids:index")

    # Get the username and password from POST data
    username = request.POST.get("username", "")
    password = request.POST.get("password", "")
    next = request.POST.get("next", "")

    # Attempt to authenticate the user if both a username and password are present
    if username and password:
        log.debug("User %s requesting login" % username)

    # Test credentials
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        log.debug("authenticated user is: %s" % request.user)
        request.session.set_expiry(46800)
    else:
        login_failed = True

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Authentication succeeded. Send the user to the original page they requested
        # using the the "next" POST data or the index.
        log.debug("Successfully authenticated user %s" % request.user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        else:
            return redirect("funbids:index")
    else:
        # Failed authenticate, send back to login page
        log.debug("Failed to authenticate user %s" % username)

# No credentials present/user failed auth - just load the page and populate the "next" form input
# in case the user was redirected here from a view they couldn't access unauthenticated.
next = request.GET.get("next", "")
try:
    template = loader.get_template("funbids/login.html")
except TemplateDoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Page Not Found")
context = {
    "pagetitle": "Welcome to FunBids!",
    "next": next,
    "login_failed": login_failed,
    "template": template,
    "request": request,
}

# Return the rendered page for display.
return render(request, template_name="funbids/page.html", context=context)
```

The debug statement prints our the username perfectly, something like:

```
[DEBUG] Successfully authenticated user adam
```

HOWEVER

Once I switch to another view, I'm no longer logged in. Instead, I'm an anonymous user, for instance:

```
def search(request):
    log.debug("request user is: %s" % request.user)
    try:
        template = loader.get_template("funbids/search.html")
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Page Not Found")
    context = {
        "pagetitle": "Search items for sale",
        "template": template,
        "request": request,
    }

    # Return the rendered page for display.
    return render(request, template_name="funbids/page.html", context=context)
```

This time the debug statement prints out:

```
[DEBUG] request user is: AnonymousUser
```

I've done some reading on the issue and found that this happens when a user authenticates, but doesn't login. However, I can login successfully without any issues, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Would appreciate any help...thanks.

Comment: Can you show your MIDDLEWARE settings please.

Comment: Of course! I haven't changed anything.
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was very subtle. Django wasn't able to get my user because my get_user method was wrong in my auth backend.

```
return User.objects.get(username=user_id)
```

should be

```
return User.objects.get(userID=user_id)
```

as the "userID" field is the primary key.